# Loading plugins in Webpack for a static website

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm building a static website,
I have downloaded some template just get things started.

There are three main JS files in this template:

```
jquery.js
plugins.js
functions.js
```

They are loaded in the index.html file in that order.
I would like to use webpack for production.

I have created a new file: index.js and in that file, used require to load these files

```
require('jquery.js')
require('plugins.js')
require('functions.js')
```

This is not working because of probably scope issues, plugins.js for example doesn't know about jquery and so on.

I can move all the plugins from plugins.js to package.json and have it downloaded to node_modules and use it from there, but because it's a static website and just a FE to my app, I don't care much about updates to its packages (and another reason, there are a lot of plugins there...).

How can I make jquery.js and plugins.js symbols to be seen by functions.js?

Thanks

Comment: That's not how modules work.  You should `import` each name you use in every file that uses it.

Comment: What do you mean? Can't I load the plugins globally? When I load a script in the HTML, jquery for example, it's being loaded globally no? Thanks

Comment: Yes, and that's a terrible idea (it makes it very hard to manage dependencies).  You should `import` everything you need in each file.